# In what way intuitionism is unique in the constructive approach

Tags: logic, philosophy, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I am writing a paper on the subjects of constructivism and intuitionism.
While I do know that intuitionism is a part of constructivism; it is also written that a lot of logic in intuitionism is unique and not shared with other constructivist approaches (such as finitism) and I can hardly understand what are the differences between the two (constructivism and intuitionism).

Thanks

Comment: Finitism is much more extreme; it says that for instance there is no mathematical object called the set of natural numbers that you can work with. Intuitionist constructionism is roughly about having your existential proofs proceed by giving an algorithm that converges to the result, in addition to an error estimate for this algorithm.

Comment: Ok, I understand this about Finitism, maybe I didnt express myself very good. How would you answer the question "In what way intuitisem is different than constructivism"

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking here. There are several meanings of "intuitionism", which range from Brouwer's personal philosophy to constructive mathematics in general.  I think that, if you clarified "constructivism" and "intuitionism" enough to clarify the question, you would likely have answered it already.   What resources have you consulted? The book *Varieties of Constructive Mathematics* is a useful reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different "flavours" and schools of *Constructivism* in mathematics.

From a "logical point of view" we may classify the different approaches as follows :

- finitism : only natural numbers, using computable functions and quantifier-free methods of proof.

See [Thoralf Skolem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoralf_Skolem) (1923), [The foundations of elementary arithmetic](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA302) and Reuben Goodstein : [Recursive number theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=WQUqvgAACAAJ) (1957) and [Recursive Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=CV28AQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1961).

- intuitionism : quantifiers are admitted but *Excluded  Middle* is rejected; this is reflected into the rejection of the inference from the absurdity of a general statement : $\forall x \lnot A(x) \to \bot$ to the existence of a witness : $\exists x A(x)$.

See [Brouwer](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/brouwer/) and [Intuitionism in the Philosophy of Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/)

- predicativism : quantifiers and the general law of excluded middle are permitetd, but [impredicative definitions](http://www.iep.utm.edu/predicat/) are forbidden.

See [Principia Mathematica](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/) and [Ramified Type Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#3) and [Hermann Weyl](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/weyl/) (1918) [Das Kontinuum](https://books.google.it/books?id=d5HtLFnz2VMC&printsec=frontcover).

More recently : [Solomon Fefereman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Feferman) (2013), [Predicative Foundations of Analysis](https://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/pfa(1).pdf).

We may add also :

- [ultrafinitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafinitism) with [Alexander Esenin-Volpin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Esenin-Volpin) (1970), [The ultra-intuitionistic criticism and the antitraditional program for foundations of mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=2PbsaZsc7mMC&pg=PR5). Only "manageable" numbers are intuitively evident, and not all finite numbers are manageable.

---

From a "more mathematical" point of view, at least four varieties of [Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#VarConMat) are available:

- [Intuitionistic Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#IntMat). See at least [Arend Heyting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arend_Heyting) (1956), [Intuitionism : An introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=prhLAAAAMAAJ) and A.S.Troelstra and D.van Dalen (1988), [Constructivism in Mathematics: An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=-tc2qp0-2bsC&printsec=frontcover), 2 volls.

See also : [John Lane Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lane_Bell), [Intuitionistic Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848901402) (2014).

- [Recursive Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#RecConMat): starting with the Russian school of [A.A.Markov (jr)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Markov,_Jr.). See Oliver Aberth : (1980) [Computable Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=lK2EAAAAIAAJ) and (2001) [Computable Calculus](https://books.google.it/books?id=sDp0enu9iEUC&printsec=frontcover).
- [Errett Bishop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errett_Bishop)'s [Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#BisConMat) : [Foundations of Constructive Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=Z7I-AAAAIAAJ) (1967).

See also Errett Bishop & Douglas Bridges, [Constructive Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=GF8lBAAAQBAJ&pg=PR3) (1985).

- [Per Martin-Löf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_Martin-L%C3%B6f)'s [Constructive Type Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#MarLofConTypThe) : [Notes on Constructive Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=uNjuAAAAMAAJ) (1968).

See also : Giovanni Sambin & Jan Smith (editors), [Twenty-five years of constructive type theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=M3sSDAAAQBAJ&pg=PR3) (1998).

In general, see also :

- Fred Richman & Douglas Bridges, [Varieties of Constructive Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=oN5nsPkXhhsC&printsec=frontcover) (1987)
- [Michael Beeson](https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~beeson/) [Foundations of Constructive Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=j6f9CAAAQBAJ&pg=PR3) (1985)
- Giovanni Sommaruga (editor), [Foundational theories of classical and constructive mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=wmJCf3d8HBUC&pg=PR7) (2011).